# SQL two table Single-row Subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, CHEF and MEAL.
What I am trying to do is to reduce salary of every chef that has not yet made a single meal.
This is my query

```
UPDATE CHEF
SET Chef_salary = Chef_salary-(Chef_salary/100 * 5)
WHERE Chef_ID=(SELECT c.Chef_ID
FROM CHEF c LEFT JOIN MEAL m ON (c.Chef_ID=m.Chef_ID)
HAVING count(m.Chef_ID)='0'
GROUP BY c.Chef_ID);;
```

It returns an error where it says that "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
What Am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The inner subquery `SELECT c.Chef_ID
FROM CHEF c LEFT JOIN MEAL m ON (c.Chef_ID=m.Chef_ID)
HAVING count(m.Chef_ID)='0'
GROUP BY c.Chef_ID` is returning more than one rows.It should return only one row if you want to run the whole update query.So run the subquery standalone you will find that more than one results are being returned.

Comment: SET Chef_salary = Chef_salary * 0.95 might give you same result, less computing, assuming a 5% reduction is what you're looking for

Comment: no need join two table. Update CHEF c Set Chef_salary = Chef_salary-(Chef_salary/100 * 5)
Where c.Chef_ID not in (Select Chef_ID from MEAL m)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE CHEF
SET Chef_salary = Chef_salary-(Chef_salary/100 * 5)
WHERE Chef_ID in (SELECT c.Chef_ID
FROM CHEF c LEFT JOIN MEAL m ON (c.Chef_ID=m.Chef_ID)
GROUP BY c.Chef_ID
HAVING count(m.Chef_ID)='0'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic correctly, you want `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE CHEF
     SET Chef_salary = Chef_salary - (Chef_salary/100 * 5)
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM MEAL m
                       WHERE chef.Chef_ID = m.Chef_ID
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update CHEF c Set Chef_salary = Chef_salary-(Chef_salary/100 * 5)
Where c.Chef_ID not in (Select Chef_ID from MEAL m)
```